# Nuance between « se sentir vivre » and « se sentir vivant »

Tags: sens

> Je suis juste un type qui ne **se sent vivre** que lorsque je suis plongé dans une recherche.
>
> Je suis juste un type qui ne **se sent vivant** que lorsque je suis plongé dans une recherche.

This is the first time I have seen « se sentir » followed by a verb, not an adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Se sentir* + verb** is definitely correct French and here, the first form is better and more widely used although the second one is getting more popular in the last decades:

[image]

Like being ***plongé dans une recherche***, ***vivre*** is something that has a duration so that one can better feel than ***vivant*** which is just a status.

This difference is probably more easy to understand when replacing ***vivre*** by other verbs.

> *Qui se sent mourir* → who find death coming / who feel like to die.
>
> *Qui se sent mort* → who feel like being dead.
>
> ---
>
> *Qui se sent rougir* → who feel a blush coming.
>
> *Qui se sent rouge* → who feel being red.

---

Edit: ***[Vivant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vivant)*** has two meanings, the first and more common one is "**alive**" and I assumed that one in my previous statements. The second meaning is "**full of life/dynamic**" and in such case, both sentences would be more or less synonymous like *qui se sent mourant* or *qui se sent rougissant* would be in my examples.

---

Finally, note that you'd better use the third person in the subordinate clause because its subject refer to ***un type*** not the first ***je***:

> Je suis juste un type qui ne se sent vivre que lorsqu'**il est** plongé dans une recherche.

Comment: When saying the sentences out loud, I feel that the sentence with the case "vivant" is a bit more intense. Also the fact that the sentence as the word "lorsque" (limiting the time of action), I feel in both cases the feeling lasts the same time.

Comment: From your examples, would it be fair to say it's like in English the difference between saying "I feel like I come alive when…" and "I feel alive when…"?

Comment: @anotherdave Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Le sens est sensiblement le même.

On pourrait dire comme autre exemple:

- je me sens chanceler;
- je me sens chancelant.

Sentir, comme tous les verbes de perception, sensation, peut être suivi d'une forme à l'indicatif :

- je le vois partir;
- je te sens venir;
- je m'entends délirer;
- je l'imagine rigoler;
- ...